# Apache - Subdomain redirect

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running a django application with fcgi
when I do this with one application, my .htaccess file looks like

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.fcgi/$1 [QSA, L]
```

and that works fine.

Now, I want to run different applications on different subdomains.
So I will create a *.fcgi file for every app. 
Basically, what I want to do is to redirect the request to subdomain.mydomain.com to the subdomain.fcgi file.

I've tryed this, but didn't work

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1.fcgi/$1 [QSA, L]
```

Comment: looks fine to me. The only thing it you'll have to put the old code behind it to catch the naked domain.

Comment: on the naked domain I have an index.html file, so I have no problem with that. But when I go to subdomain.mydomain.com I get a 500 error message.

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between `[QSA,` and `L]`.

Comment: I've deleted this and didn't work. The problem (I guess) was that it couldn't access the file in a different domain's (on this case, the naked domain) folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it.

Inside the public_http folder, I have one folder for every subdomain, Inside of each subdomain's folder, I have a dispatch.fcgi file. And the .htaccess file now is:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.llulai\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/dispatch.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

The downside, is that on the url.py file, the url patterns should start with

```
    r'^subdomain/$'
```